# Is there software that will convert bidirectional TCP traffic from one port to another?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, port, tcp

I have an application that needs to send and receive traffic on a certain TCP port, say 5000.
The server component uses port 6000.

> Is there any software that will allow me to "TCP bridge" these two ports together?

I'd like to run this TCP bridge on either a AWS or Azure hosted platform.  Since I know C# pretty well a .NET solution would be ideal.

Comment: Uhm, just setup a NAT between the server and client?

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: @Zoredache Can a NAT translate incoming data on port 80 and forward it to port 8080?

Comment: @Massimo  Windows preferred, C# language preferred

Comment: NAT operates on the packet headers.  Depending on implementation it can change either the source/destiation addresses and ports.

Answer (score 2):

> [Balance](http://www.inlab.de/balance.html) is a simple but powerful generic tcp proxy with round robin load balancing and failover mechanisms. Its behaviour can be controlled at runtime using a simple command line syntax.

Bridge ports:

```
balance 5000 6000
```

(Connections to the local port 5000 are forwarded to port 6000)

Or bridge to a port on a remote server

```
balance 5000 remote:6000
```

Or round robin between localhost:6000, remotehost:6000 and otherhost:6000

```
balance 5000 localhost:6000 remotehost:6000 otherhost:6000
```